# JavaScript random function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, random, nan

I am trying to make a simple inclusive random function, but for some reason it gives me NaN. I copied this function from Mozilla reference. Thanks.

```
var size = {min:1, max: 1700}; 

function getRndInt(min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generate() {  
document.getElementById("Text1").innerHTML = getRndInt(size.min - size.max);
}
```

Comment: Your `getRndInt()` function takes 2 arguments, but you're just passing one.

Comment: you wrote `size.min - size.max`: did you mean `size.min, size.max` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll be more attentive in the future.

Comment: Please mark an answer as resolving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getRndInt function that you have defined needs two parameter (min, max).

```
function getRndInt(min, max)
```

But you are passing only one

```
getRndInt(size.min - size.max);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is because of subtraction `-` sign, parameter need to comma `,` separated

```js
var size = {
  min: 1,
  max: 1700
};

function getRndInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generate() {
  console.log(getRndInt(size.min, size.max));
}
generate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to have sent two arguments to your function. You only sent one..

```js
var size = {min:1, max: 1700}; 

function getRndInt(min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generate() {  
document.getElementById("Text1").innerHTML = getRndInt(size.min,size.max);
}

generate();
```

```html
<div id="Text1"></div>
```